# Create virtual webcams and stream video into them using Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyvirtualcam

It's possible to create devices in /dev that simulate webcams

using python to stream video from local dictory into these virtual devices?

For example, streaming a video to this virtual webcam device and it will be available on `/dev/video3`

Comment: What do you mean by 'create multiple virtual cams'?

Comment: Ubuntu identifies the system as /dev/video1 and /dev/video2 when there are two webcams. So, without a webcam, need to create a virtual cam and stream the video to this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create devices in ```/dev``` that simulate webcams and stream video into these virtual devices?

Comment: I think you want `v4l2loopback` https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback

Comment: @ewong Yeah you are correct. I want to simulate a web kind of thing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think this will work for me. Let me try this